# Summarize data using pivot table

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

I am trying to review the budget for our department at work, but it is an insane amount of data that is organised as followed:

[image]

I am trying to use a pivot table to see the changes per month for each cost center, but I can't get Excel to do this for me. I would like to plot to this in a graph like this:

[image]

I am using office 365 excel with windows 10.

Comment: you will need to `un pivot` the data, will write up a full answer when I have time

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use Power Query to get the result:

1. Select the **Range**- go to **Data**- **From Table/Range**:
   [image]

2.In **Power Query Editor**- select Columns `from Month 1 to Month 7`- Go to **Transform**- Select **Unpivot Column**- select `Cost Column` and `Value Column`- Select **Pivot Column** and **Value Column option** is **Value**:
[image]

3. Go to **Home**- Select **Close & Load**- **Import Data** select **Pivot Chart**:
   [image]
4. Add `Attribute` to **Axis (Categories)** and `X`,`Y` to **Values**- change chart type from **Column** to **Line**:
   [image]

Comment: Is PowerQuery free and usable without admin rights?

Comment: What version of Office did you use?

Comment: I used Office 365